# View does not load after form submission through jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, forms, codeigniter

I have the following form:

**Html:**

```
<form name="NewProductForm" id="NewProductForm" action="http://localhost/tddd27/index.php/AddProduct/AddToDatabase">    
<br><label>Product Name:</label>
<input name="ItemName" type="text"/></br>
<br><label>Category:</label>
<input name="ItemCategory" type="text"/></br>
<br><label>Description:</label>
<input name="ItemDesc" type="text"/></br>
<br><label>Price:</label>
<input name="Price" type="text"/></br>
<input type="text" name="ID"  value="<?php echo $ID; ?>" hidden="true" >
<input type="text" name="Name"  value="<?php echo $Name; ?>" hidden="true">
<input type="button" id="_NewProduct" name="_NewProduct" value="Submit">
</form>
```

when the user click a button jQuery submit this form.

**jQuery:**

```
 $("#_NewProduct").click(function(){
        $("#NewProductForm").submit();
      });
```

The form calls a CodeIgniter Controller which calls a Module, and inserts the product in the database. I want after that another view to be loaded. So I wrote:

```
function AddToDatabase()
      {
          $ItemName=$_GET['ItemName'];
          $ItemCategory=$_GET['ItemCategory'];
          $ItemDesc=$_GET['ItemDesc'];
          $ID=$_GET['ID'];
          $Price=$_GET['ItemDesc'];
          $this->load->model('AddProductModule'); 
          $this->AddProductModule->AddProductOnTable($ItemName,$ItemCategory,$ItemDesc,$ID,$Price); 
          $data=array('ID' => $_GET['ID'], 'Name' => $_GET['Name']);
          $this->load->view ( 'adminview',$data);
          exit;
      }
```

The problem is that the `load->view` does not seem to load the view. After the submission everything goes well and the product is in the database, but an empty page is loaded instead of the `adminview`. Any idea what is the problem?

Comment: Y to have `exit;` at the end???

Comment: I don't know CodeIgniter but I'd say the `exit` is your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not want to exit after the controller method runs...Codeigniter still has things to do after that.